# Include Does Not Work In Codeigniter 4.1.9

Tags: codeigniter-4

Hye, I'm still trying to dive in to learn some of the framework such as Codeigniter and Laravel, but i stumbled into a problem which is $this->include does not work, I am trying to include file that have html code... I've tried looking on the internet, trying out several other method but it still does not work

Here What I've Been Trying,

```
$this->include('test');
```

I've Also Tried Using The Controller Code Which Is,

```
return view('test');
```

And Lastly, I've tried,

```
$this->load->view('test');
```

But none of them works.

Comment: Did you try checking the docs? https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/outgoing/views.html

Comment: Do you have a view named "test" in the app/View directory?

Answer (score 0):

Try `echo view('test');`

[Loading Multiple Views](https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/outgoing/views.html#id4)

Answer (score 0):

`echo view_cell('view file',[$datas=>$values])`

https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/common_functions.html?highlight=view_cell#view_cell

Answer (score 0):

I've moved to CI 4.4.1 from V3.? and found I need to echo the include view:-

```
echo $this->include('test');
```